# MySQL: How to do date between by year and month (no date)

Tags: mysql, database

If there are 2 columns in mysql database: year; month, now I want to do a sum calculation based a year-month range without specifying the date. Let's say 2010-11 to 2011-07, how can I realize it?

```
SELECT * FROM TT WHERE F1 BETWEEN '2010-11' AND '2011-07'
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: You also need to provide the first day of each month.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to take all rows from 2010-11 to 2011-07, until the first day of August:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE `date_column` BETWEEN '2010-11-01' AND '2011-08-01'
```

Use this query if you want to get all rows from the full months of January to June:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE YEAR(`date_column`)=2011 AND MONTH(`date_column`) BETWEEN 1 AND 6
```

If you want to use different years, then write different queries for each year:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE 
  (YEAR(`date_column`)=2010 AND MONTH(`date_column`) BETWEEN 11 AND 12) OR 
  (YEAR(`date_column`)=2011 AND MONTH(`date_column`) BETWEEN 1 AND 7)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, if `F1` is of type `date`

```
SELECT * FROM TT WHERE F1 BETWEEN '2010-11-01' AND '2011-07-31'
```

and this if `F1` is of type `datetime`

```
SELECT * FROM TT WHERE F1 BETWEEN '2010-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-07-31 23:59:59'
```

if year and month are saved in different columns then use this

```
SELECT * FROM TT WHERE DATE(CONCAT(year_column, '-', month_column, '-01')) 
BETWEEN '2010-11-01' AND '2011-07-31'
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across to the same situation and successfully managed by doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM `TT` WHERE CONCAT(year_column,month_column) between '201011' and '201107';
```

hope it helps others also..

Answer (score 0):

also you can use this for single and multiple years

for example data between :   year = 2022 , month = 7   and   year = 2023 , month = 6

```
SELECT * FROM `TT` 
WHERE (year > 2022 OR (year = 2022 AND month >= 7)) 
AND (year < 2023 OR (year = 2023 AND month <= 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

```
SELECT * FROM TT 
WHERE CONCAT(YEAR(F1),'-', LPAD(MONTH(F1),2,'0')) 
     BETWEEN '2023-05' and '2023-06'
```